# Can we use Linq to sort a class based on its ID without implementing IEnumerable

Tags: linq

I am new to Linq and tried to learn its intricacies.
I have a normal class (not derived from anything) with a unique ID and I would like to use Linq to sort a list of that element of the class above.

```
 class item
    {
        public int itemID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
    class items
    {
        List<item> myItems = new List<item>();

        public List<item> test()
        {
            List<item> t = myItems.Sort((x,y) => (x.itemID.CompareTo(y.itemID))).ToList<item>();
            return t;
        }
    }
```

The error I got was "Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'void'". itemID is an int and I should be able to compare it with another int... What am I missing?

Comment: `List` implements `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `OrderBy`:

```
return myItems.OrderBy(x => x.itemID);
```

Sorting lists explicitly is rarely needed these days. Prefer a functional programming style.

Answer (score 2):

The `Sort()` method you are using is not a LINQ extension method, it is a native `List<T>` method, which sorts the list in place. So there is no return value, and that is causing your problem. Try like this:

```
class item
{
    public int itemID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
class items
{
    List<item> myItems = new List<item>();

    public List<item> test()
    {
        myItems.Sort((x, y) => (x.itemID.CompareTo(y.itemID)));
        //return myItems.ToList<item>(); // unneeded transformation
        return myItems;
    }
}
```